# Formula for number of combinations in the forward direction for a list of numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I have a list of numbers e.g. 15, 20, 12. I want a formula to find the number of combinations in the forward direction i.e. the possible combinations as per my requirement are [15], [15, 20], [15, 12], [20], [20, 12], [12], [15, 20, 12] and therefore the required number of combinations is 7.

Example-2: for 15, 20, 12, 30, the possible combinations as per my requirement are [15], [15, 20], [15, 12], [15, 30], [20], [20, 12], [20, 30], [12], [12, 30], [30], [15, 20, 12], [15, 20, 30], [15, 12, 30], [20, 12, 30] [15, 20, 12, 30] and therefore the required number of combinations is 15.

Comment: Isn't it just $$2^{\text{# of elements}}-1$$Since it's just the powerset minus the empty set.

Comment: @DonThousand - I have updated my question with a couple of examples.

Comment: Why isn't $[15,12,30]$ a possibility in example $2$?  There are several others left out.  Don Thousand's answer in the first comment is correct, soo far as I can see.

Comment: @saulspatz - Thanks. I've found my mistake and also the answer. Thanks, everyone for so quick help.